# Openlayers CQL.js compare attribute columns

Tags: openlayers-2, cql-filter

I'm trying to use a CQL filter in OpenLayers in order to identify some polygons in which the value of one column is higher then the other. So, when I use the following cql filter

production_2010 > production_2008

I get an error ERROR: In parsing: [production_2008], expected one of: VALUE: /^('([^']|'')*'|\d+(.\d*)?|.\d+)/

The funny thing i that GeoServer CQL filter will allow such comparison (done using the layer preview web page).

So, from what I understand, OpenLayers CQL.js can only parse filters that have an attribute column name on the left and a value on the right?